# Prevent exploding loss function multi-step multi-variate/output forecast ConvLSTM

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a plausible problem that currently fails to solve. During the training, my loss function explodes becomes inf or NaN, because the MSE of all errors becomes huge if the predictions (at the beginning of the training) are worse. And that is the normal intended behavior and correct. But, how do I train a ConvLSTM to which loss function to be able to learn a multi-step multi-variate output?

E.g. i try a (32, None, 200, 12) to predict (32, None, 30, 12). 32 is the batch size, None is the number of samples (>3000). 200 is the number of time steps, 12 features wide. 30 output time steps, 12 features wide.

My ConvLSTM model:

```
    input = Input(shape=(None, input_shape[1]))
    conv1d_1 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation=LeakyReLU())(input)
    conv1d_2 = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation=LeakyReLU())(conv1d_1)
    dropout = Dropout(0.3)(conv1d_2)
    lstm_1 = LSTM(32, activation=LeakyReLU())(dropout)
    dense_1 = Dense(forecasting_horizon * input_shape[1], activation=LeakyReLU())(lstm_1)
    output = Reshape((forecasting_horizon, input_shape[1]))(dense_1)
    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

My ds generation:

```
                ds_inputs = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(df[:-forecast_horizon], None, sequence_length=window_size, sequence_stride=1,
                                                                          shuffle=False, batch_size=None)
                ds_targets = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(df[forecast_horizon:], None, sequence_length=forecast_horizon, sequence_stride=1,
                                                                          shuffle=False, batch_size=None) 
                ds_inputs = ds_inputs.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
                ds_targets = ds_targets.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
                ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_inputs, ds_targets))
                ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=(len(ds)))
```

Besides MSE, I already tried MeanAbsoluteError, MeanSquaredLogarithmicError, MeanAbsolutePercentageError, CosineSimilarity. Where the last, produce non-sense. MSLE works best but does not favor large errors and therefore the MSE (used as metric has an incredible variation during training). Additionally, after a while, the Network becomes stale and gets no better loss (my explanation is that the difference in loss becomes too minor on the logarithmic scale and therefore the weights cannot be well adjusted).

Answer (score 1):

I can partially answer my own question. One issue is that I used ReLu/LeakyReLu which will lead to exploding gradient problem because the RNN/LSTM Layer applies the same weights over time leading to exploding values as the values add up. Weights will not be reduced by any chance (ReLu min == 0). With Tanh as activation, it is possible to have negative values which also allow a reduction of the internal weights and really minimize the chance of exploding weights/predictions within the network. After some tests, the LSTM layer stays numerical stable.